# NVD3 Chart Clicl Event with Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, nvd3.js

I'm using NVD3 linePlusBarChart. Thanks to this there is also a focus chart.
I would like to add a click event on it.

I was able to make it works when there is no focus but when I focus the chart, the click event doesn't work anymore.

How can I make my click event works anytime (focus or not focus)?

Here is my code:

```
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
        .margin({top: 50, right: 60, bottom: 30, left: 70})
        .x(function(d,i) { return i })
        .y(function(d,i) {return d[1] });

    chart.xAxis
      .showMaxMin(false)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d][0] || 0;
        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
      });

    chart.y1Axis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',f')(d)});

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        .datum(testdata)
        .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

    d3.selectAll(".nv-bar").on("click", function(e) {
        alert(JSON.stringify( e ));
    });

    return chart;
});
```

Comment: have you tried `d3.selectAll("g")` ?